# Linux command to find all the files with same name but different extension in a directory?

Tags: linux, file, command-line

I am working on a project where i need to deal with lots of files with the same name but different extensions.

please suggest a command/solution to get the file name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your helper here is find command

```
find /<directory_name> -name  <file_name.\*>
```

Comment: Yes, especially if you use `find . -name fname.*`

Answer (score 0):

```
find "$searchdir" -name "${filespec%.*}".\*
```

will find all files in `$searchdir` named "foo" with a file extension if `$filespec` is of the form "foo.bar".

Of course, if `$filespec` is of the form "foo.bar.baz", you will find all files named "foo.bar" with a file extension, so beware of such files.

If you want only the root filename (e.g. "foo.bar.baz.quux" -> "foo"), then you should use `%%` instead of `%` after the `filespec` variable.

If you need to strip a preceding directory name from the filespec, you could combine this with the `basename` utility:

```
find "$searchdir" -name "$(basename "${filespec%.*}")".\*
```